# Looking for a side menu for the new Xamarin IOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin

In Xamarin there is the choice to choose between the IOS classic and the new IOS version to develop native IOS apps.

I have chosen for the new IOS project. but this version uses Xamarin.IOS in place of MONOTOCH foundation.

and i'm looking for a library for adding a slide in menu to my app.

do anyone now any nuGet pacakges or GitHub packages that i can use?.

Comment: What is your question? Please clarify and remove unnecessary information. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: i'm searching for a slide in sidemenu that works with UIKit and not with Monotoch.foundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these libraries. I think that's what you need  https://github.com/thedillonb/MonoTouch.SlideoutNavigation

https://github.com/jdehlin/Xamarin-Sidebar

Comment: I've tried these two libraries already. they use the monoTouch Reference and that can't be used in combination with the Xamarin.IOS Reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how far down the road you are with the project but sounds like your just getting started. If so a Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms) has a MasterDetail View that I believe renders as a sliding left menu on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Give a chance also to JASidePanels, it's published by **Xamarin Inc** so it should be possible to have their support on Xamarin forum and I suppose they will keep updating it whenever will be necessary.

Most recent versions support also ios64.

Here the link to the component but I think it's possible to use it just referencing the library and following the samples.
Since it also exist the native version of JASidePanels should be also easier to find around examples on how to customize or solutions in case of problems.

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/jasidepanels/true